# clicking or changing input, disables others

Tags: jquery, events, input, disabled-input

```js
$(function() {
    $('.disablesothers').on('change focus click', function () {
   var $input = $(this).find('input');
   var $brothers = $input.parent().siblings('.disablesothers');
   console.log($brothers.length);
      $input.removeAttr('disabled');
   $brothers.find('input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
});
```

```css
input:disabled {
   border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="overlabel tab_content default tooltip disablesothers" title="Bind text">
  <span>Destination name, zone</span>
  <input type="text" name="hotel_name">
</label>
<label class="overlabel disablesothers">
  <input type="text" name="other_hotels" id="other_hotels">
</label>
```

Note that I am binding the event on the label, not the inputs,

But this don't work

Any idea why?

-EDIT-

This could be because `removeAttr` it's not actually removing it, just clears the value.. ?

Comment: Your question should include the intended behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by adding a transparent div wich covers the label when the input is disabled, because some browsers won't fire the event if it's a disabled input,

```
<label class="overlabel disablesothers">
  <input type="text" name="other_hotels" id="other_hotels">
</label>
```

then,

```
:checked + div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.prop('disabled', true)` instead of `.attr('disabled', 'disabled')`:

```js
$(function() {
    $('.disablesothers').on('change focus click', function () {
   var $input = $(this).find('input');
   var $brothers = $input.parent().siblings('.disablesothers');
   console.log($brothers.length);
      $input.removeAttr('disabled');
   $brothers.find('input').prop('disabled', true);
    });
});
```

```css
input:disabled {
   border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="overlabel tab_content default tooltip disablesothers" title="Bind text">
  <span>Destination name, zone</span>
  <input type="text" name="hotel_name">
</label>
<label class="overlabel disablesothers">
  <input type="text" name="other_hotels" id="other_hotels">
</label>
```

As the docs for [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) state:

> To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the checked, selected,
>   or **disabled** state of form elements, use the .prop() method.